# Bundler cannot find i18n-0.8.6 when attempting to install petergate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

What I tried to do I tried to run

```
rails g petergate:install
```

I expected it to add a migration and insert petergate into my User model.

What actually happened is I got an error in terminal saying:

```
Could not find i18n-0.8.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I ran `bundle install` and retried `rails g petergate:install`, but the same error keeps occurring.
When I view my gems, I do have `i18n-0.8.6`.

```
$ rails g petergate:install
Could not find i18n-0.8.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
$ bundle install
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.6
```

I am not sure how to debug this.
The petergate gem is in my `Gemfile`:

```
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'microurb_view_tool', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'petergate', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.5'
```

The following commands have been run for debugging purposes:

```
$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep i18n
      i18n (~> 0.7)
    i18n (0.8.6)

$ bundle exec rails g petergate:install
Could not find i18n-0.8.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails:update:bin' (see --tasks)
/Users/danale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/danale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/danale/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: can you verify the version of `i18n`: `cat Gemfile.lock | grep i18n`

Comment: see for yourself above, I actually have two versions that I added later on while trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: You might have upgraded your rails version without upgrading bin/ folder. Try this: `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin`

Comment: What happens if ỳou run `bundle exec rails g petergate:install`?

Comment: @Oxfist, I posted it above.

Comment: @Cyzanfar, I added the results above.

Comment: I created a new Rails project, added the petergate gem and ran `rails g petergate:install` and had no issues so I'm guessing something could be wrong with your Ruby or gems installation paths. Can you confirm `ruby -v`, `rails -v` and `bundle -v` output the expected versions?

Comment: @Oxfist, damn you hit it right on! As soon as I read ruby -v, I remembered I had did an rvm 2.4 to create a new ruby gem last night. I switched back to 2.3.3 and rails g petergate:install works! Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to confirm that `ruby -v`, `rails -v` and `bundle -v` outputs the expected versions, since Rails could be using a different gemset.